# Do I need a sine wave UPS for late 2013 Mac Pro?

Tags: hardware, mac-pro, ups

The support person at CyberPower told me that my late 2013 Mac Pro has a PFC power supply therefore,  I would need to get an UPS with sine wave output.

Is this a correct statement?

Comment: This would appear to say 'no' ... https://superuser.com/questions/912679/when-do-i-need-a-pure-sine-wave-ups

Answer (score 2):

The CyberPower rep is only partially correct:

- Yes, you do have a PFC power supply
- No, you don't need a pure sine wave UPS to run the Mac Pro specifically or any Mac generally.

### Mac Pro Power Efficiency

Apple puts out an [excellent document](https://www.apple.com/lae/environment/pdf/products/desktops/MacPro_PER_oct2013.pdf) (PDF) on the efficiency of the Mac Pro.  But specifically, it get a 90% power efficiency rating at 100V, 115V and 230V which far exceeds the 85% minimum threshold set by the EPA to be [Energy Star v6.0](https://www.energystar.gov/products/office_equipment/computers/key_product_criteria) compliant

[image]

From EPA Energy Start requirements:

> Internal power supplies: 85% minimum efficiency at 50% of rated
> output, 82% minimum efficiency at 20% and 100% of rated output, with
> Power Factor > 0.9 at 100% of rated output for power supplies with >=
> 75W output power

### Apple Power Supplies

Apple's power supplies from the base model MacBook to the top of the line iMac Pro all use power supplies with high efficiency

- [MacBook Environmental Report](https://www.apple.com/environment/pdf/products/notebooks/MacBook_PER_April2016.pdf)
- [iMac Pro Environmental Report](https://www.apple.com/environment/pdf/products/desktops/iMac_Pro_PER_dec2017.pdf)

To achieve this level of efficiency, [this basically requires PFC](http://www.cooperindustries.com/content/dam/public/bussmann/Electronics/Resources/Brochures/Power_Factor_Correction_(PFC)_Application_Notes.pdf).  Looking at [a tear down of a MacBook power adapter](http://www.righto.com/2015/11/macbook-charger-teardown-surprising.html), we can see the PFC circuitry.

[image: MacBook Charger Teardown]

So, bottom line is that your Mac Pro has a PFC power supply

### UPS with sine wave output.

Unless you are running *sensitive* (and that being the operative word) equipment that will react badly to non-sine wave or simulated sine wave power output, you have no need for this.  By *sensitive*, I mean things like scientific instrumentation, network communication gear (telco), high-end audio electronics, etc.

Apple's products are robust enough to withstand the fluctuations in standard UPSes and from the electrical grid.

From personal experience, I have used UPSes (Uninterrupted Power Supply) from APC and CyberPower purchased at the local big box store on sale; and as a resident in FL with frequent power outages during the summer months, neither have failed to keep my computers (Apple, Dell, Synology, etc.) running without issue.

## TL;DR

Yes, you have a PFC (Power Factor Corrected) power supply.  All Apple computers have a PFC power supply.

No.  You don't need a “sine waveform UPS”.  It will not hurt to get one, but your benefits will be negligible; a standard UPS will work fine.

It's likely the rep is reading a Feature/Benefit chart and attempting to up-sell you on a product you don't really need.

Answer (score 0):

No - the support person you spoke with is confused. The [specifications that Apple has published for the late 2013 Mac Pro](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp697?locale=en_US) make no mention of a power factor corrected input. And as far as the Mac Pro having a PFC power supply, it may well have one... but that's so that you ***don't*** have to buy a pure sinewave UPS!

If you speak with him again, invite him to join the discussion here, and make his case :)