# Magsafe 87w detected as 94w

Tags: magsafe

I bought a 87W MagSafe charger for my 15-inch 2018 MacBook Pro from online marketplace (I'm not sure if it's genuine; the seller mentioned it's OEM). However, upon testing, the AC Charger Information in the system report indicates a wattage of 94W. Is it safe for my MacBook Pro and its battery if I use this charger regularly?

Comment: The rated wattage is a maximum; it does not 'push' that much energy into your laptop at all times. The laptop draws the power that it needs. It should have the Apple logo recessed into it, if it's genuine.

Comment: @benwiggy thanks for comment, but in my case, the wattage exceeds the maximum stated wattage. Is it normal?

Comment: As Allan says: it's likely the seller just got the wrong description. Is there perhaps a model number somewhere that you could check?

Comment: @benwiggy  '87w' is printed on the body of the MagSafe btw, so the seller didn't misdescribe the product. It doesn't display a serial number when using system_profiler so I think it's not genuine. The seller said this MagSafe is an OEM product supposedly made by the same factory that produces MagSafe in China, but it's sold without going through Apple's distribution. So, is it still safe to continue using this magsafe?

Comment: Factories in China are well known for 'running-on' -- so if Apple order 1 million units, they actually produce 200,000 more, which they sell themselves. It's illegal, of course. But you don't know whether these have been through the same Quality Control (or if they passed it). It could be identical to an Apple unit; it could not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I bought a 87W MagSafe charger for my 15-inch 2018 MacBook Pro… a wattage of 94W. Is it safe for my MacBook Pro and its battery if I use this charger regularly?

First, [it’s always safe to use a charger with a higher wattage rating](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/402879/119271).  The *device* draws the power from the charger, it’s not pushed into the device.  The wattage rating is the *maximum* amount of power it can supply.

Now, while it's safe to use a charger with a higher wattage rating that what's required, you always want to use quality chargers from brands you know and trust or ideally, direct from the manufacturer (Apple).

### Check that your Charger is Genuine

#### Using System Report

Go to * → About this Mac → More Info → System Report*.  Once it's generated (should only take a second or two at most), go down to *Power* section and you should see the *AC Charger Information* section.

If the item is genuine, it will say that it was manufactured by Apple and have a SN# that can be verified.

[image]

#### Using Terminal

You can obtain the same info provided by System Report by using the `system_profiler` command.

```
system_profiler SPPowerDataType | awk '/AC Charger/,/Power Events/ { print }'
```

This command will extract the following block from the output.

```
AC Charger Information:

  Connected: Yes
  ID: 0x701c
  Wattage (W): 68
  Family: 0xe000400a
  Serial Number: ******************
  Name: 70W USB-C Power Adapter
  Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
  Hardware Version: 1.0
  Firmware Version: 1030030
  Charging: Yes
```

Secondly, it sounds like the seller sent you a higher rated charger (by mistake) provided it’s not counterfeit. Given that there’s no 94W charger, but there is a 96W and the [chargers designed to work with your particular Mac are USB-C based](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201700) meaning power delivery is negotiated,  it’s most likely only drawing 94W From the charger at that moment.

In my example here, I purchased the 70W charger and I am currently drawing 68W.  This is perfectly normal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Allan. It seems that the MagSafe is indeed not genuine. It doesn't display a serial number when using system_profiler. '87w' is printed on the body of the MagSafe btw, so the seller didn't misdescribe the product. When I contacted the seller, they said this MagSafe is an OEM product supposedly made by the same factory that produces MagSafe in China, but it's sold without going through Apple's distribution that's why it's cheaper. So, is it still safe to use this MagSafe?

Comment: I wouldn't use it.  What they are doing is illegal and Apple can have customs easily block this because it's blatant IP theft.  This is counterfeit and I wouldn't attach my expensive MacBook to this. Always spend the few extra dollars to get from a known good brand like Anker or buy genuine.

Comment: Also, I wrote [an answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/337452/119271) about the charger and one thing to note is that the power adapter is *optically* isolated.  The DC  (computer) side is not connected whatsoever from the mains side.  Cheap power adapters don't do this.

Comment: Thanks Allan!